# Android Spinners in ListView, do I have to use a ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have an issue with `Spinners` in a `ListView`. I have a `ListView` with a `CheckBox`, a label, and two `Spinners`. The `Spinner` are populated from SQLite and that is working fine. I am not using the `ViewHolder` method because so far when the `ListView` row is clicked the `CheckBoxes` are checked or unchecked and the change is immediately saved to the database. When the row is checked the `Spinners` are made visible but are not visible when the row is not checked.

So the issue that I haven't managed to find a solution for is that I have no idea how to get the actual `Spinner` or even get the `ListItem` row that the clicked `Spinner` is on. The `Activity` extends `ListActivity`. Anyone know a way I can do this without using a `ViewHolder` or do I have to use a `ViewHolder`?

Here is the code that declares and populates the `ListView`:

```
mSsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllSsPlaylistSs(mPlId);
        startManagingCursor(mSsCursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{"pl_selected", BTDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, BTDbAdapter.KEY_NAME2};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.pl_selected, R.id.name, R.id.name2};

        mAllSs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.pl_edit_ss_row, mSsCursor, from, to);
        mAllSs.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        //custom handling of setting the value
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if(columnIndex == 3) {
                    ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup)view.getParent().getParent();
                    mSId = cursor.getInt(0);
                    if (cursor.getInt(3) > 0) {
                        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_selected);
                        mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                        mTSpin = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_t_spin);
                        mMSpin = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_m_spin);
                        mtvT = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_t);
                        mtvM = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_m);
                        mTSpin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mtvT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mMSpin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mtvM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //set the values in the t spinner
                        PopulateTSpinner(cursor.getInt(4));
                        //set the values in the m spinner
                        PopulateMSpinner(cursor.getInt(5));
                    }
                    else {
                        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_selected);
                        mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                        mTSpin = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_t_spin);
                        mMSpin = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_m_spin);
                        mtvT = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_t);
                        mtvM = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_m);
                        mTSpin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mtvT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mMSpin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mtvM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }                   
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    setListAdapter(mAllSs);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the code for your adapter.

Comment: I do realise that I would probably get a performance increase by using a `ViewHolder` to avoid looking up the views every time setViewValue is called but I am new to this and haven't quite gotten my head around how they work yet and if I can immediately commit the changes to the database doing it that way.

Comment: For what do you want to get the spinners? Are the `CheckBoxes` really working? Right now you're setting the values of the `CheckBoxes` correctly from the database but you don't have a listener attached to them so maybe visual they are working but it shouldn't be able to save the new state in to the database.

Comment: I probably should have said that the CkeckBoxes are declared as unclickable in the xml, so setting Checked and updating the DB is done in the onListItemClick() for the list view. I want this behaviour so the user doesn't have to click on the actual checkbox to select or deselect it, I want them to be able to click anywhere on the row for this.

Comment: it is probably a rather complicated interface.

Comment: Imagine first there is a list of items(item1). Each item could be selected or not selected for this list(checkbox). Each item also has two other different lists of items (item2 and item3 respectively) associated with it. The child lists of items (2 and 3) are different for each item in the parent list(1). So once that parent item is checked the spinners are made visible and populated only with the child items data relevant to that parent item. What I want to do is take that child item when selected and save it to the db. I hope that clarrfies things a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the code really relates to what I am trying to do here because I can't simply set an object to equal the view (spinner) since there is one with the same id for each row. I can't use a selection changed listener because it would require a separate listener for each row I believe and I have no idea how many rows there will be, potentially a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question: If your app flow is:

> show a list of data(`CheckBox` + `TextView`(`Spinners` hidden)) ->
>   user clicks a row(the `Spinners` appear for that row with(individual) data) ->
>   user selects something in those `Spinners`->
>   save that selection in the database

then I think you should go with a custom adapter and take care yourself of the row creation + data binding(I don't see how you would set a listener for the `Spinners`). Below is a small example on how you might do this(although probably not a pretty way of doing it):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); // the holder
                                                            // pattern
            // set the text for the TextView in your row
            holder.name
                    .setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            // status of the CheckBox from the database
            int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("pl_selected"));
            // set the CheckBox status
            holder.ckb.setChecked((status > 0) ? true : false);
            // get the id of this particular row, we'll use this later in the
            // Spinner's listeners
            long theId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            // see if it is time to show the Spinners
            if (status > 0) {
                // it is time to show the Spinners. Here you would do stuff
                // like: setting up the Spinner's adapters + setting the
                // listener
                // I used a Spinner with entries set in the xml layout(so my
                // selection result is a String)
                holder.spin1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.spin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // set theId as a tag so you know which Spinner was acted on
                holder.spin1.setTag(new Long(theId));
                holder.spin1
                        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                                Long realRowId = (Long) parent.getTag();
                                // I don't know
                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                // the column where I saved the spinner selected
                                // item is called "saved_item"
                                cv.put("saved_item", (String) parent
                                        .getItemAtPosition(position));
                                // mDb is my SQLiteDatabase instance
                                mDb.update("tbl", cv, "_id = ?",
                                        new String[] { String
                                                .valueOf(realRowId) });
                                // I don't know how you saved the data, the
                                // above is just an example
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            }
                        });
                // also implement the second Spinner like the first one
            } else {
                // required to prevent a recycled View from causing damage
                holder.spin1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.spin2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapters_listspinner_row,
                    parent, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.spin1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            holder.spin1.setFocusable(false);
            holder.spin2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            holder.spin2.setFocusable(false);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.ckb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.ckb.setFocusable(false);
            v.setTag(holder);
            return v;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            Spinner spin1, spin2;
            TextView name;
            CheckBox ckb;
        }

    }
```

Also, the required `onListItemcClick` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // manage the CheckBox state
        CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        ckb.setChecked(!ckb.isChecked());
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("pl_selected", ckb.isChecked() ? 1 : 0);
        mDb.update("tbl", cv, "_id = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        // requery the database so the changes are seen by the adapter, this is horrible! 
        Cursor re = mDb.query("tbl", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        mAllSs.changeCursor(re);
    }
```

As an advice, maybe you could modify the layout of your app and move the `Spinners` out of the `ListView` row.

Comment: I have thought about simplifying the layout by showing a different view when the user checks the row to select the additional values but this is something that I would like to avoid if possible. I think the interface will be much nicer if I can do it this way. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, will try out the method that you have suggested when I get a chance and will let you know if I got it working. Thanks again @Luksprog, I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Just thought I would give this a quick update, seems to be working correctly, still have a bit of work to clean this up and I am still working on getting the data I need in the setOnItemSelectedListeners for the spinners but the event is firing when I select something from the spinners so almost there. Thanks for your help Luksprog.